# Access Key from Entity that's instantiated but not stored [objectify] [@prepersist]

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have written a @PrePersist method that's called before my User object is persisted.  The purpose of the method is to make a kind of reservation for the User, so no one else can take his email address.  So, when the User is about to be persisted, I say, "create an EmailReservation for user #xyz."

My trouble is in getting the #xyz when the User has not been persisted before.  The id is null, but I cannot use DatastoreService.allocateIds because the Entity that will represent my User has already been made.  I do have access to that Entity, but getKey() returns a key with a null id - it hasn't yet decided what its id will be.

So, I'm hoping one of the following is possible:

1. Figure out the id that an Entity will have when it's persisted
2. Give an Entity that's already been created a specific id before it's persisted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to know what ID an entity will have when it's persisted; the only way to do so is to use allocateIds.

You will have to either generate an ID before creating the User object, passing it in, or do your work after the entity has been written to the datastore.